# I want to open multiple elinks at regular interval of 6 seconds

Tags: linux, shell, sh, elinks

I want to open multiple elinks at regular interval of 6 seconds

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in 1 2 
do

echo "Looping ... number $i";
elinks  'http://google.com' ; q ; sleep 6; elinks  'http://google.com'; q ; sleep 1800;

done
```

HOw do I quit 1st elink and open another one , Any command for that ? Manually q or ^C is working , but i want a shell script command

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quit `elinks` by killing it using `killall elinks`.

Here is the final script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for i in 1 2 
do
    echo "Looping ... number $i"
    elinks 'http://google.com' &
    sleep 6
    killall elinks

    elinks 'http://google.com' &
    sleep 1800
    killall elinks
done
```

Comment: After killall elinks , Next iteration in the loop is not working as manual dailog box is appearing  , How do I bypass the exit alert by command at backend.?

Comment: Can you live with a non-graceful termination? In this case, `killall -s KILL elinks` should do the job.

Comment: @himanshubindal Sorry, I made a small mistake! I have edited the code now and it should be working now :)

Comment: @himanshubindal If my answer works, could you please accept my answer by clicking on the check mark?

Comment: Where , How ...?